# How to install PowerShell 3.0

Tags: powershell-3.0

I tried to install PowerShell 3.0 for Azure and follow [Steps](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/06/02/weekend-scripter-install-powershell-3-0-on-windows-7.aspx) .

It is not working for me. Any one suggest other tutorials for steps or what I missed?

Comment: Let me see. I bet you got an error message.

Comment: I am trying to install "windowsazure-powershell.0.6.18" but it is showing "Required PowerShell 3.0 or higher version"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long R&D my problem has been resolved by using the following steps :

1. Upgrade Window 7 to Window 7 SP1.
2. Install .net framework 4.0 or higher (if already not required)
3. Install Window Management Framework 3.0 [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595)
4. Install Azure Powershell SDK [from here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/)